# Serializing and Deserializing a List<String[]> JTable

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, jtable, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize data from JTable in a class called Ex, i'm getting a behaviour related to Jtable and DefaultTableModel which i don't understand.
I'm using a `List<String[]>` as data container, which i'm not sure how to deserialize.

```
public class Ex implements Serializable {
static List<String> S1 = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<String[]> Z1 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
Ex
{
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {Z1.add(new String[] {(i+1)+"",((i+1)*10)+"",((i+1)*100)+""});}
data = new DefaultTableModel(Z1.toArray(new Object[][] {}), S1.toArray());
tab = new JTable(data);
...
}
}
```

Serialization and Deserialization methods called using buttons look like this

```
public void Serializer(Ex caller)
{
    try {
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Ser.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
    os.writeObject(caller);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
}

public void Deserializer()
{
    Ex J = null;
    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Ser.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    J = (Ex) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    DefaultTableModel data2 = new DefaultTableModel(J.Z1.toArray(new Object[][] {}), J.S1.toArray());
    tab.setModel(data2);
}
```

MyTableListener looks like this :

```
public class MyTableListener implements TableModelListener
{
    Ex x;
    MyTableListener(Ex E) {x=E;}
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {   int row = e.getLastRow();
        int col = e.getColumn();
        String[] rowBuffer = x.Z1.get(row);
        rowBuffer[col]=(String)x.data.getValueAt(row,col);
    }
}
```

and in main method :

```
...
Ex THIS = new Ex();
Tlistener = new MyTableListener(THIS);
data.addTableModelListener(Tlistener);
...
```

Can anyone specify how to properly deserialize `List<String[]>` please?

Comment: Regularly "serialization" is done to a stream or byte array. Your class **Ex** mainly mirrors the table model. Why not using the two Vector-s as required by method DefaultTableModel.setDataVector() ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved :
Static fields do not get serialized.